# Amplitude of the steady-state response to undamped spring-damper system subject to forcing function $e^{-at}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find the amplitude of the steady-state solution to the following undamped equation of motion:

$$m \ddot{u} + k u = p_0 e^{-at}$$

The question is asking to prove that the steady-state amplitude is:

$$\frac{u_o}{(u_{st})_o} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^2/\omega_n^2}} $$

I solved the particular solution to be:

$$u_{p} = \frac{p_o}{{m\omega_n^2}(1+\frac{a^2}{\omega_n^2})}$$

I solved the maximum static amplitude to be:
$$(u_{st})_o = \frac{p_o}{k} $$

I found that the total solution is:

$$u(t) = \frac{p_o}{m\omega_n^2(1 + \frac{a^2}{\omega_n^2})}(\frac{a}{\omega_n}\sin(\omega_nt) - \cos(\omega_nt) + e^{-at}) $$

I used the method of undetermined coefficients and the boundary conditions $u(0)=0$ and $\dot{u}(0)=0$.

I'm just not sure how to proceed from here. From the problem, it states that $u_o$ is the maximum amplitude of $u(t)$. Please advise!

Note: I used the formula $\omega_n = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$ for substitution of $k$ values to $\omega_n$.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way answer this question is obtained using the Laplace transform.

Applying the Laplace transform we obtain

$$
\hat u(s) = \frac {p_0}{(ms^2+k)(s+a)}+\frac{1}{ms^2+k}\left(s u_0+u'_0\right)
$$

or

$$
\hat u(s) = \hat u_p(s)+ \hat u_h(s)
$$

where $\hat u_p(s) = \frac {p_0}{(ms^2+k)(s+a)} = \frac{sA+B}{ms^2+k}+\frac{C}{s+a}$ is the particular transform and $\hat u_h(s) = \frac{1}{ms^2+k}\left(s u_0+u'_0\right)$ is the homogeneous transform. Solving the values of $A,B,C$ we obtain

$$
\cases{
A = -\frac{m p_0}{m a^2+k}\\
B = \frac{a m p_0}{m a^2+k}\\
C = \frac{p_0}{m a^2+k}
}
$$

now if the initial conditions are null we have $\hat u_h(s) = 0\Rightarrow  u_h(t) =0$ and regarding the particular solution, as $\frac{C}{s+a}$ assuming $a\gt 0$, represents a decaying exponential, finally we have

$$
\hat u(s) = \frac{sA+B}{ms^2+k}
$$

with anti-transform

$$
u(t) = \frac{A \sqrt{k} \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{k} t}{\sqrt{m}}\right)+B \sqrt{m} \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{k} t}{\sqrt{m}}\right)}{\sqrt{k} m}=R\cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{k} t}{\sqrt{m}}+\phi_0\right)
$$

with $R$ the sought amplitude.